# What is this ザガガッと sound based off?

Tags: onomatopoeia

### The Problem

Currently reading a passage where a Goblin's sword and the Main Protaganist's Dagger just clashes together and it gives this sentence:

> 鎧{よろい}ゴブの剣が**ザガガッと**ダガーの刃の上を走って、鍔{つば}でも止められない、etc...

The Offical Translation has it as

> There was a scream of metal on metal as the... etc

I can understand from the translation that the **ザガガッと** is a sort of onomatopoeia for whats happening but I can't find out where it's from / based off.

---

### The Question

Where does this originate from or what is it based off of?

Thanks,

Archie ♥

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ザガガ should be a combination of [ザッ](http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/browse/za/)/ザザッ and [ガッ](http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/browse/ga/)/ガガッ, both of which describe "hard" sounds of mechanical impact. It expresses a little longer sound (or sounds in rapid succession) because it has three kana. I think you don't have to remember this because this combination is fairly rare.